# Ubuntu live USB not shown as bootable device in bios

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb, partitioning

I'd like to make a bootable Ubuntu USB with a writable partition
for storing backups and data.  I want the USB to be bootable for
mobility, i.e. I'd be able to boot it on another arbitrary machine,
like a library machine, or one at a hotel.  So the boot installation
must be 'live', like a live DVD.  However, if I just 'burn'
a bootable .iso image to USB with Startup Disk Creator for example,
the drive is now read only, i.e. iso9660 format.  gparted, parted,
fdisk and other tools cannot touch it because iso9660 does not
support write operation.  And even if I forced write of a partition
table sector with dd to the first sector, I'll have just overwritten
part of my iso9660 boot code.

My machine is UEFI (though it hardly matters, because I will not
necessarily know the configuration of a machine I might use the
drive on).

So, I first partitioned the drive with gparted (or tool of choice).
The partition evidently has to be FAT32 (or maybe FAT16), and at
at least as large as the .iso image, and flagged it 'boot' and 'esp'
(for UEFI booting).  Then I 'burned' the .iso to the partition with
dd.  I can use the unallocated space for data partition(s) later.

It doesn't show up in the boot manager menu as a bootable device/
partition.  I'm not sure about the incongruity of an iso9660
file system residing on a fat32 partition, though gparted doesn't
give me an option to create an iso9660 partition.  Maybe I need
to toggle the 'removable device' bit on the drive?  How do I make
this work?

Comment: Why don't you just install Ubuntu on your USB?

Comment: Make sure you are using an USB port that is attached to your chipset, not to an additional USB-chip on your Mainboard. The latter are often not usable for booting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [multiboot](http://multibootusb.org/). It works for a single ISO too (that would be your case).

`multiboot` creates bootable USB disk that can boot from multiple ISO images. If you use FAT32 or NTFS, you will be able to use the disk in other systems too.

You will be able to either write directly to the partition holding the ISOs or create a *persistence area* to be seen by the images (a loopback mounted at boot time).

Comment: I updated the answer. Please note that this is about booting, and the ability to use the disk for other stuff comes as a bonus. Let's not turn this into _what filesystem runs where_. More on the filesystem choice (from a `multiboot` perspective) can be found [here](http://multibootusb.org/page_guide/#requirements).